# OpenTok not working on older Android (org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class maybe missing)

Tags: android, react-native, opentok

I have a React Native Android app with an OpenTok view (written as a native module). I'm experiencing a crash problem (immediately upon attempt to instantiate OpenTok view) affecting older Android versions (SDK 16-19, Jelly Bean through KitKat), with any OpenTok session. More recent Android phones have no issues; OpenTok works perfectly.

Here is the relevant Android logcat output:

```
11-12 16:30:12.993 2949-2949/com.myapp I/OpenTokUnifiedView: APIKEY Connect Session
11-12 16:30:13.003 2949-2949/com.myapp I/OpenTokUnifiedView: apiKey: ********** sessionId: ********** token: **********
11-12 16:30:13.023 2949-2949/com.myapp I/dalvikvm: threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/data/app-lib/com.myapp-1/libopentok.so)
11-12 16:30:13.033 2949-2949/com.myapp I/dalvikvm: threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/data/app-lib/com.myapp-1/libopentok.so)
11-12 16:30:13.033 2949-2949/com.myapp I/dalvikvm: threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/data/app-lib/com.myapp-1/libopentok.so)
11-12 16:30:13.033 2949-2949/com.myapp I/dalvikvm: threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/data/app-lib/com.myapp-1/libopentok.so)
11-12 16:30:13.033 2949-2949/com.myapp I/dalvikvm: threadid=1: recursive native library load attempt (/data/app-lib/com.myapp-1/libopentok.so)
11-12 16:30:13.053 2949-2949/com.myapp E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.opentok.android.Session.init(Native Method)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.opentok.android.Session.<init>(Session.java:710)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.opentok.android.Session$Builder.build(Session.java:588)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.myapp.OpenTokUnifiedView.connectSession(OpenTokUnifiedView.java:114)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.myapp.OpenTokUnifiedView.setApiKey(OpenTokUnifiedView.java:72)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.myapp.OpenTokUnifiedViewManager.setApiKey(OpenTokUnifiedViewManager.java:34)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateViewProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:83)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackViewManagerSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:129)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:48)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager.updateProperties(ViewManager.java:34)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.createView(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:227)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$CreateViewOperation.execute(UIViewOperationQueue.java:153)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$1.run(UIViewOperationQueue.java:809)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.flushPendingBatches(UIViewOperationQueue.java:922)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue.access$2100(UIViewOperationQueue.java:47)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIViewOperationQueue$DispatchUIFrameCallback.doFrameGuarded(UIViewOperationQueue.java:982)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.uimanager.GuardedFrameCallback.doFrame(GuardedFrameCallback.java:31)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:136)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:107)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:759)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.webrtc.voiceengine.BuildInfo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.myapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp W/System.err: ... 34 more
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp E/rtc: #
# Fatal error in ../../webrtc/modules/utility/source/helpers_android.cc, line 68
# last system error: 2
# Check failed: !jni->ExceptionCheck()
# Error during FindClass: org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo
#
11-12 16:30:13.063 2949-2949/com.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000b85 (code=-6), thread 2949 (ale.app.staging)
```

Since it looked like org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class was missing, I manually added audio_device_java.jar as a library (as recommended on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/PkfAVr_TYQs ) to see if it fixed the issue.

However, it looked like OpenTok SDK already had it when I tried to build, so manually adding audio_device_java.jar did not help:

```
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class
```

Not sure why the app on older Android is missing org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class. What could be happening on older Android?

EDIT: I found that this actually works on Lollipop -- modified this question to reflect that the issue affects up to SDK 19 (KitKat).

Comment: Any Solution ???

Comment: Not yet. I've opened a support ticket with TokBox; hopefully an answer will come soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved it on my own! Posting here so that others may find this useful.

I had `multiDexEnabled` set to `true`, so I needed to explicitly specify certain classes to keep for the older platforms to use OpenTok properly (SDK 19 and earlier).

This means that I had to include `multiDexKeepProguard` in my app/build.gradle `defaultConfig`:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
    multiDexKeepProguard file('proguard-rules.pro')
    ...
}
```

In my `multiDexKeepProguard` file (mine happens to be a text file named `proguard-rules.pro` in the `app` directory), I had to make sure to include the following lines:

```
# Keep the following for OpenTok
-keep class com.opentok.** { *; }
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; }
```

This allowed my OpenTok mobile app to work properly for SDK 16 (Android 4.1 Jelly Bean) through SDK 27 (Android 8.1 Oreo).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by adding webrtc jar file into android project

1. Download libjingle_peerconnection_java.jar file from https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bElH-Krh56cO2S8Biyp0LSFurjcxFIcT
2. Place it into libs/ folder
3. Run your application

If you got "**Multiple dex files define android Logging.class**" then follow below steps

1. Extract your .jar file
2. Remove Logging class files from the folder (org.webrtc)
3. Finally Compress it as .jar and utilise it, your error will resolve.

That's it.

Comment: I've retrieved the libjingle_peerconnection_java.jar file and have tried to include it in my libs/, but almost every single file in it is already in my project. Even after removing all of the duplicates and creating new .jar files from the result, this doesn't seem to be the solution for my case.

Comment: Your major issue was "duplicate entry: org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class", then follow below steps

1. Extract your .jar file, 
2. Remove BuildInfo class files from the folder (org/webrtc/voiceengine), 
3. Finally Compress it as .jar and utilise it, your error will resolve.

Comment: What happened was that the crash happened because the app thought that I did *not* have org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class -- and that's why I manually added it in a audio_device_java.jar file. And that's when I saw the duplicate entry issue. My first quote block (logcat output) showed a *missing* org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class, and my second quote block (build output) showed a *duplicate* org/webrtc/voiceengine/BuildInfo.class. That's why it's so strange, and why I posted my original question.

Comment: That means, you have two "BuildInfo.class" in two jar files. So you have to remove one class file from any one jar file.

Comment: But if I don't add the jar file, then the build behaves like there is *no* BuildInfo.class ... And that's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to OpenTok version 2.21.4 and issue solved in android 12 and above.